# How to setup dynamically database file in cakephp like as wordpress cms?

Tags: cakephp

I want to setup cakephp database file dynamically.
After doing this i want to insert username, password ,site name etc into related tables dynamically like wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConnectionManager::create()` to create a dynamic datasource connection. As an example:

```
ConnectionManager::create('dynamic_connection_name', array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    //etc
);
```

Then you can set it on any model with:

```
$this->useDbConfig = 'dynamic_connection_name'
```

Please look at the docs for further reference:
http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ConnectionManager.html#_create

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_put_contents` to create the file

```
$dbConfig = "<?php ".PHP_EOL;
$dbConfig .= "class DATABASE_CONFIG { ".PHP_EOL;
    $dbConfig .= "\t".'public $default = array('.PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'persistent' => false,".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'host' => 'localhost',".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'login' => 'username',".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'password' => 'password',".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'database' => 'databasename',".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'prefix' => '',".PHP_EOL;
        $dbConfig .= "\t\t'encoding' => 'utf8'".PHP_EOL;
    $dbConfig .= "\t ); ".PHP_EOL;
$dbConfig .= "} ".PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents(ROOT.DS.'Config'.DS.'database.php', $dbConfig);
```

Comment: I have got connection manager problem in main core files.so any way to create this file using forms.